# Convert wired volume control to wireless

Tags: speakers, volume, wireless

I have an older (circa 2000) Cambridge Soundworks speaker set (four wired speakers with a subwoofer/receiver) that still puts out pretty good sound but is collecting dust. I thought it would be nice to hook up to a play room tv. The only problem is the volume control/balancer is a wired input to what I'm pretty confident is a [6 pin mini DIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector) and getting up to change the volume by hand constantly would be annoying.

I'm guessing there must be a wireless/bluetooth aftermarket device I could use to replace this wired control so I could control the volume at least (maybe even the balance?) with a connected app on my phone? Been googling like crazy but can't seem to find the right search term / device type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a reverse-engineering and electronics challenge. I would start by dismantling the controller to determine the control method, then start investigating arduino based solutions, possibly with a VCA chip controlling the volume. It's do-able, but not easy.

Comment: Do-able yes, but the design effort is substantial. One must have as well  electronics hardware  design and computer programming skills farfarfar beyond anything that one can find and learn by googling a day. A person with knowledge equivalent of 2...3 years of serious electronics engineering studies might solve the case.